# Is it a commonly used spoken contraction to pronounce "the interviewers" /ðɛntər vjuwərs/?

Tags: pronunciation

This guy is saying (https://youtu.be/nhTcuUvLGOE?list=PLD6t6ckHsruYoalxbzcjX1TNn4h7ShiRk&t=271)

> Don’t give your entire work history; **the interviewers** can get that from your CV if they want it.

where "the interviewers" sounds like /ðɛntər vjuwərs/, is it a commonly used spoken contraction or just his own accent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "the interviewers" isn't a common enough phrase to get its own contraction, if that's what you mean.  But assuming you mean this as an example of a more general case, then yes. It is common for *the* to run quickly into the following word, with the vowel almost disappearing if unstressed, and possibly "merging" into the opening vowel of the next word (where applicable).  Personally I'm not sure I hear ɛ in this example - I would probably have notated it as ɪ, but the reality is probably more of a dipthong somewhere between the two.

Comment: "It is common for the to run quickly into the following word, with the vowel almost disappearing if unstressed ...", the "the" before "interviewers" is unstressed, right?

Comment: Yes.  Unstressed the is usually something like ðə, stressed ði.